# What are good implementations of high dimensional volume estimation in Python?

Tags: python, math

I wanted to estimate the volume of a high dimensional shape in Python. I have an oracle for querying if I am inside the shape or not. I am in high dimension (at least `32*32=1024` dimensions). I ideally don't want to implement it myself because:

1. seems highly technical with papers ranging in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0120.pdf and it seems something a non expert can get easily wrong
2. it seems to be a standard mathematics question (estimating volumes in high dims) so it seems sensible to assume a better optimized code than what I can hack in python might exist.

Does someone know what is a good way to solve this? Should I go ahead an implement the one in the paper I linked?

---

Not sure what what the mathematical technical constraints may be but:

1. I have access to an oracle that says +1 or -1 depending if I'm inside the shape or not.
2. I want to estimate the shape of a convex shape

Right now I am just tempted to go ahead an implement something like:

1. decide on a really bid sphere that most probably contains the shape I want to estimate
2. sample many points (it would be nice to know **how many I need to sample** have a good estimate of my shape)

however, since it seems a subtle technical field, I'd rather not get too hacky if I can avoid it (especially if I can get theoretical guarantees on the # of samples)

---

Related links before I posted question:

- https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-are-the-fastest-algorithms-to-implement-in-practice-that-estimate-high-dimensional-volumes
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0120.pdf
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/computing-volume-of-high-dimensional-convex-polyhedra
- http://www.qhull.org/

Comment: I doubt plain sampling will be practicable. As a simple example suppose your shape was a 1024 dimensional cube of side L, and you sampled uniformly from a containing cube of side 1. If L is 0.99 then the volume of the wee cube is around 3.4e-5, so if you drew 100000 samples you might get the volume to 10%. But if L is 0.9 then the volume is ~ 1.4e-47 and you'd be sampling for ever...

Comment: It looks to me like O(d^4) is best you can get with known algorithms for a general convex object. (Your first link is specific to polytopes, which makes things considerably simpler, but is still O(m n^3) in complexity.) I don't really think this is computationally feasible for the number of dimensions you are asking for.

Comment: @AlexisOlson dam, that seems to take `(1024^4)/(60*60*24*365)=34.865K` years. Well I guess I need a different method than the ones suggested.

Comment: What is the application of this problem that you are trying to solve? Perhaps a different angle of attack would work better.

Comment: @AlexisOlson the problem I am solving was described in the question I believe, but the gist is that I want to estimate the volume of a (unknown) shape by querying an oracle that tells me if I am inside the shape or not.

Comment: Let me try @AlexisOlson's question again: people don't typically wake up and say "today, I need to estimate the volume of an unknown shape by querying an oracle".  More likely, it's "I need to estimate this volume to get 30$ by winning a contest, so that I can buy this autobiography", in which case we could propose easier ways to earn 30$, or used bookstores, or maybe we could warn you the book is self-serving with many glaring omissions.  If you just want the volume to admire, there's not much to be done, but knowing the _reason_ you want it can help find new paths to your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your question: how many sample points do you need to estimate the volume of some region in high dimensions.

Assume that the set K is contained in some enclosing set B whose volume is known to be 1 without loss of generality. Denote by V the unknown volume of K. Let f(x) denote the indicating function of K: f(x) = 1 if x is in K, and f(x) = 0 if x is not in K. (Apologies, no LaTeX on stackoverflow).

Clearly, V is exactly the expectation E[f(x)], which is also the probability P[f(x)=1], where the random variable x is drawn uniformly at random in B. Furthermore, the variance var(f(x)) is precisely V(1-V), which is bounded between 0 and 0.25.

For x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub> drawn uniformly and independently at random in B, consider the sum S<sub>n</sub> = (f(x<sub>1</sub>) + ... + f(x<sub>n</sub>))/n. The central limit theorem says that S<sub>n</sub> is asymptotically a normal distribution N(V,var(f(x))/n), so the standard deviation of S<sub>n</sub> is sqrt(V(1-V)/n). Therefore, if you want a absolute accuracy of ε (i.e. |S<sub>n</sub>-V|≤ε) with probability p = 0.999999998027 (i.e. 6 standard deviations), you should take n = 36V(1-V)/ε<sup>2</sup>.

Especially when V is tiny, you are going to want a relative tolerance, i.e. ε = δV. Then, you need n = 36(1-V)/(Vδ<sup>2</sup>).

The problem that you see here is that it's very tough to get tight accuracies for the case when V is small, but what makes this bad is the curse of dimensionality, which roughly says that V is likely to be O(10<sup>-d</sup>) in dimensions d.

For example, if K is the sphere of radius 1/2 inscribed in the cube B of side 1, then V is approximately (πe/(2d))<sup>d/2</sup>/sqrt(dπ), and if you want a relative error less than 100%, then you're going to need just about n = O(d<sup>d/2</sup>) samples.

Comment: so is for `d>1024` essentially impossible to do this with only an oracle?

Comment: What I proved is that a straight Monte Carlo approach doesn't work. If you put in more assumptions, e.g. using the papers you cited in your question, then it's a different thing.